# How to Generate Combinations in Parallel in Golang

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

I'm trying to generate combinations (e.g. every 6 combo out of 10 numbers) in parallel using Golang.

I have a solution that runs serially: [Serial Code](https://play.golang.org/p/pumPyZkx08r)

For the case where the number of items(n) = 3 and the sample size (r) = 2, the output is:

```
Got  [1 2]
Got  [1 3]
Got  [2 3]
```

Now I have tried parallelizing this and here is that code: [Parallel Code](https://play.golang.org/p/VPw_sT2scgP).  It doesn't work and I don't know why.  For the same problem the output is:

```
Put  [3 3] into the channel.
Got  [3 3] out of the channel.
Put  [3 3] into the channel.
Got  [3 3] out of the channel.
Put  [3 3] into the channel.
Got  [3 3] out of the channel.
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a data race.

```
$ go run -race main.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c0000b0018 by goroutine 11:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:33 +0x11e

Previous write at 0x00c0000b0018 by goroutine 9:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:33 +0x11e

Goroutine 11 (running) created at:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:35 +0x211

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:35 +0x211
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000b0010 by goroutine 12:
  runtime.slicecopy()
      /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/slice.go:197 +0x0
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:21 +0x39c

Previous write at 0x00c0000b0010 by goroutine 10:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:33 +0x11e

Goroutine 12 (running) created at:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:35 +0x211

Goroutine 10 (running) created at:
  main.combinationUtil()
      /home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concomb/main.go:40 +0x2dc
==================
```

This data race is caused by writing to the underlying array of `data` concurently - which means, underlying array of `data` (and thus the content of `data`) is shared on all goroutine. That is undesired.

In Go, what is under the hood of `slice` is a slice header (see `reflect.SliceHeader`), it keeps in three bytes the `len`, `cap` and `ptr` to the underlying array. When you copy it, it does not copy the underlying array, but rather only the header, so the underlying array is shared and raced - neither is desired.

To avoid that, just make a new copy of it. (using sync techniques may avoid race, but the content is still shared). However, that alone is a costing operation, both in terms of time and space. Whether that will worth the benefit of having parellel (if there is any benefit), is another topic and out of scope of this answer.

For example,

```
newdata := make([]int, r)
copy(newdata, data)

// current is included, put next at next location
newdata[index] = arr[i]
wg.Add(1)
go combinationUtil(ch, wg, arr, n, r, index+1, newdata, i+1)

// current is excluded, replace it with next (Note that
// i+1 is passed, but index is not changed)
wg.Add(1)
go combinationUtil(ch, wg, arr, n, r, index, newdata, i+1)
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/YebyCGapSMs

Note 1: This simple addition of a copy works only because that the recursion does not relies on change of part of `data` (`data[index:]`). Otherwise, there needs to be a back-copy for `newdata` to `data`.

Note 2: As I implied before, I doubt how efficient is this kind of parellel. There can be other ways of calculating combinations in parellel, which may utilize power of parellel calculation better, but requires quite different algorithms. However, I am not certain of that, so you should do your own research if interested.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much.  Yes I hear you re different algorithms and the time/space aspect of the copying.